# In Jenkins, does a multibranch pipeline support Git tags?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Using a multibranch pipeline I see a list of all my Git branches.

However, I would expect git tags to appear in the list also but they don't seem to be listed.

Is this expected behaviour or is this possibly a config issue? Are tags supported? If tags are not supported, is there a plugin that can work in harmony with the multibranch pipeline to support tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem you're facing is described in Jira issue [JENKINS-34395](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34395).

As far as I understand, the multibranch plugin does not support tags and is focused only in building branches. The workaround suggested is to have two separate builds, one for a normal branch build and second (seems not configured with a Jenkinsfile) to build a tag.

Update, 14.04.2021:

Jenkins does support tag builds now as described in this [post](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/05/16/pipelines-with-git-tags/) but tag builds may not run automatically because of build strategy. Refer to this [comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-47496?focusedCommentId=317789&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-317789) for some details.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be by design, see [JENKINS-47496](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47496) and [here on so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006786/4312669).
Seems that one still needs separate build jobs for release tags.

Comment: What do you mean separate builds? I'm trying to create a separate multibranch pipeline with only tags in it, to build on new tag push, but I'm unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: This is no longer the case. The multibranch pipeline plugin supports tag builds.

Comment: @Kissaki do you have any links for more info, please?

Comment: @hertzsprung check this one out jenkins.io/blog/2018/05/16/pipelines-with-git-tags/#configuring

Comment: I don’t have a link right now but I use it at work. In the pipeline job configuration you can add additional Git options, and add "Discover tags" alongside "Discover branches" and it will list in a separate tab to branches and build them.

Comment: @Kissaki could you provide any more information? i have a separate tab showing up with my tags, but builds are not running on them automatically. is there anything else you have setup?

Comment: @WilliamReed Please have a look into this [post](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/05/16/pipelines-with-git-tags/). You also need to enable build strategy for tags. See this [comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-47496?focusedCommentId=317789&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-317789)

Answer (score 7):

Actually Jenkins multibranch pipeline **does support** build on tag.

In Jenkins, go to the configuration of your multibranch pipeline.

In `Branch Sources` -> `Behaviors` -> click on `Add` and select `Discover tags`:

[image: Jenkins multibranch pipeline config for tags]

In the screenshot above, I listen branches `develop`, `main`, `feature/*` and I also filter tags in the format `vX.Y.Z`.

Once you validate this configuration, you will see two tabs in the main view of the pipeline (`branches` and `Tags`):

[image: Jenkins multibranch pipeline view branches and tags]

Comment: I posted this answer as it is one of the main `google` results when you search for `git tag on multibranch jenkins pipeline`