# Execute Jenkins Pipeline step only when building a tag

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have certain build logic, such as publication, that I would like to have Jenkins perform only when it is building a Git tag.  How can I accomplish this using Jenkin's Declarative Pipeline?

In other words, I am trying to build functionality equivalent to Travis CI's deploy on tags functionality:

```yaml
deploy:
  [...]
  on: 
    tags: true
```

There  is a [built-in condition to check the branch](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions), but I do not see one that indicates the tag.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euzGc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euzGc.png) https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin/ it works for me. same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146616/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-build-tags-using-the-multibranch-pipeline-jenkin

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update:** As of version 1.2.8 of the [Pipeline Model Definition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Model+Definition+Plugin)  you can now use [`buldingTag()`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when):

```groovy
stage('Deploy') {
  when {
    buildingTag()
  }
  steps {
    echo 'Replace this with your actual deployment steps'
  }
}
```

---

When using the [Multibranch Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-multibranch) configuration you can use the `expression` condition along with the `TAG_NAME` environment variable provided by the underlying [Branch API Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/branch-api).  Unfortunately, you can't directly check if the environment variable is defined at the Groovy level (API restrictions) so you have to test in in the shell:

```groovy
stage('Deploy') {
  when { expression { sh([returnStdout: true, script: 'echo $TAG_NAME | tr -d \'\n\'']) } }
  steps {
    echo 'Replace this with your actual deployment steps'
  }
}
```

The above takes advantage of non-empty strings being truthy in Groovy.

An easier way may be introduced in future versions.  See [jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin#240](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/pull/240).

Comment: Can somebody explain what does the expression in the 2nd example should do? Sadly buildingTag() doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @user568021 or whomever - it appears the expression opens a shell, executes a script to echo the `TAG_NAME` environment variable, removes the newline, and returns the result which it evaluates as either empty string (`false`) or non-empty string (`true`), so if TAG_NAME has a non-empty value it returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

## Declarative Pipelines

### Execute STAGE only when building for Tag

For a whole stage, @vossad01 already provided the answer to use `buildingTag()` within a `when` like

```
stage('Deploy') {
  when {
    buildingTag()
    beforeAgent true
  }
  steps {
    echo 'deploy something when triggered by tag
  }
}
```

the `beforeAgent true` is optional and ensures to check the condition before executing on an agent.

### Execute STEP only when building for Tag

In case it's just about a step within a stage that should be conditional on a tag, you can use Groovy syntax (as used in Scripted Pipelines) inside a `script` block as follows.

```
stage('myStage') {                                              
  steps {                                                       
    echo 'some steps here that should always be executed'
    script {                                                    
      if (env.TAG_NAME) {                                       
        echo "triggered by the TAG:"                                 
        echo env.TAG_NAME                                       
      } else {                                                  
        echo "triggered by branch, PR or ..."                              
      }                                                         
    }                                                           
  }                                                             
}
```

### Additional hint to build for Tags

You may also be interested in the [basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin) that enables to trigger builds when pushing tags (which is not enabled per default). See [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) for how to use it. You can install it via `Manage Jenkins` -> `Manage Plugins` -> `Available tab` and then use the Search bar.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation which I handled by getting the branch name ,in case of tag it is like `refs/tags/v101.0.0-beta8468` , so you have to extract / parse this to check if its a tag otherwise its just the branch name like `pipeline` . eg.

```
if(env.gitlabBranch.contains("tags"))
    {
        isTag = true
        echo "----------------true----------------"
        branch = env.gitlabBranch.split("/")[2]
        imageTag = branch

    }
    else
    {
        branch = "origin/$env.gitlabBranch"

    }
```

And in the chekout step mention the branch as

```
 branches: [[name: "${branch}"]
```

if you want to checkout from the same project. 
Based on the isTag variable you can choose to run a certain stage .
Like:

```
if(isTag) {
stage('Deploy') {
   // your logic here
}
```

initialise your isTag as false :)